# ARM Cortex M3 How do I determine the program counter value before a hard fault?

Tags: arm, embedded, interrupt, cortex-m, program-counter

I have an embedded project using a STM32F103 (ARM Cortex M3), it is getting a occasionally getting hard fault in release mode. As part of recovery, I would like to retrieve the PC value from before the hard fault and store it for later debugging in the battery backed region.

How would I determine the value of the program counter at the point of the hard fault? Obviously, the PC is now set to its location within the hardfault interrupt.

Where should I look? It there an address for the normal mode register bank?

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know too, but you might get a better answer on chiphacker.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cortex-M3 uses a quite different model of exception handling from the "classic" ARM, e.g. it doesn't have "abort mode" mentioned in the other post. I suggest you to read [this app note](http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf). For example, for the Hard Fault:

> The value of SCB->BFAR indicates the memory address that caused a Bus Fault
>   and is valid if the bit BFARVALID in the SCB->CFSR register is set. The
>   value of SCB->MMFAR indicates the memory address that caused a Memory
>   Management Fault and is valid if the bit MMFARVALID in the SCB->CFSR
>   register is set.

To determine the PC value at the time of exception you need to examine the stack; the processor pushes R0-R3, R12, PC and LR before executing the handler. The stack used can be either Main (if bit 2 of LR is 0) or Process (otherwise). See page 13 of the app note for details.

Comment: Thanks Igor, how do I fetch the PC from the stack?

Comment: You need to fetch PSP or MSP and get a word at offset 0x18 from it. See an example implementation here: http://embdev.net/topic/170640#1636052

Comment: Still trying to figure this out. Is this offset 24 bytes above the MSP?: uint32_t *pc = (uint32_t *) ((char *)_get_MSP() + 24);

Comment: You should do it in assembler, the compiler might adjust the stack value before it gets to your code.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing that. Just correcting for the offset and getting the proper PC value now. I'll need to test in release mode to ensure the offset doesn't change. Thanks again!

Comment: See also http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html for a nice hard fault handler implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual](https://silver.arm.com/download/download.tm?pv=1073121) in the section on Exceptions.  You need to register to get it.

Typically a relevant address will be put in the link register LR (R14), but the precise meaning varies according to the exception, and there are varying offsets.

W.r.t. accessing the User/System mode register bank, I think you need to switch the mode to access it.

Comment: Ahh, cool! Just checked it while debugging (have no clue how to invoke a hard fault currently ;p ) and it indeed shows the address of the caller.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK, I see it is not the caller, but the return address.

Comment: I generated the hard fault by: *((char *)0x00) = 5;

Answer (score 1):

When an exception occurs, the processor state change from the current state to the *abort* state. In the abort state the processor shifts to use a new set of registers for sp and lr (sp_abt and sp_lr respectively. For a data abort, the offending instruction can be found in lr_abt + 8 for an prefect about in lr_abt + 4 (as per the ARMv7 Architecure reference manual)

Comment: changed sp_abt to lr_abt quite a bad mistake on my part - fixed now

Comment: This is valid for classic ARM but not Cortex-M3

Comment: I think you meant lr_abt-8 and lr_abt-4.

Answer (score 1):

I have an FAQ on this very topic.  The page linked to from the FAQ includes [fault handler code](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) that will obtain the program counter from the stack for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a common cause for these issues are those 'for loop' delays. When using -O3 they simply get optimized away if you are are not referring to volatile variables. Personally, I prefer the SysTick approach.

Comment: Thanks @leppie, whole heartedly agree. No for loop delays here, I;m also using SysTick for my counting. Every thing is in a state machine as well, to avoid blocking. I think the problem would present itself in debug mode if I gave it enough time.