# C code calling an Assembly routine - ARM

Tags: c, assembly, arm, call, cortex-m

I'm currently working on a bootloader for an ARM Cortex M3.

I have two functions, one in *C* and one in *assembly* but when I attempt to call the *assembly function* my program hangs and generates some sort of fault.

The functions are as follows,

**C:**

```
extern void asmJump(void* Address) __attribute__((noreturn));

void load(void* Address)
{
    asmJump(Address);
}
```

**Assembly:**

```
.section .text

.global asmJump

asmJump:                   @ Accepts the address of the Vector Table
                           @ as its first parameter (passed in r0)

    ldr r2, [r0]           @ Move the stack pointer addr. to a temp register.
    ldr r3, [r0, #4]       @ Move the reset vector addr. to a temp register.

    mov sp, r2             @ Set the stack pointer

    bx  r3                 @ Jump to the reset vector
```

And my problem is this:

The code prints "Hello" over serial and then calls `load`. The code that is loaded prints "Good Bye" and then resets the chip.

If I slowly step through the part where `load` calls `asmJump` everything works perfectly. However, when I let the code run my code experiences a *'memory fault'*. I know that it is a memory fault because it causes a `Hard Fault` in some way (the Hard Fault handler's infinite while loop is executing when I pause after 4 or 5 seconds).

Has anyone experienced this issue before? If so, can you please let me know how to resolve it?

As you can see, I've tried to use the function attributes to fix the issue but have not managed to arrive at a solution yet. I'm hoping that someone can help me understand what the problem is in the first place.

**Edit:**

Thanks @JoeHass for your answer, and @MartinRosenau for your comment, I've since went on to find [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368360/arm-thumb-using-bx-in-thumb-code-to-call-a-thumb-function-or-to-jump-to-a-thu) that had a very thorough explanation of why I needed this label. It is a very long read but worth it.

Comment: If you have different interrupt routines for bootloader and application: Have you disabled interrupts and replaced VTOR (vector table offset register) with the vector table of the second program? This should be done before setting the stack pointer.

Comment: 1) Are you sure the stack pointer is correct? 2) If your code is THUMB code then r3 must not be the address of the code but the address of the code plus 1!

Comment: Try flushing the *write buffer*, *dcache* and *icache* before your call.  Did you copy code somewhere?  It sounds like a *code* `!=` *data* issue or pipeline effect; which explains it working when paused in the debugger.

Comment: @user694733 I have not disabled the interrupts but you're right that I should. Still, once an interrupt is serviced it should return back to the code it was executing before, i.e. my reset vector.

Comment: @MartinRosenau 1) The stack pointer is retrieved from the Vector Table which is generated by the linker so I'm confident that it is correct. 2) That is exactly what the problem was and Joe Hass' answer helped me realize that.

Comment: @artlessnoise I did try using the `dsb`, `isb` instructions but they were not the problem. It was a far sillier mistake. I simply did not know that my assembly was not treated as thumb code without the `.thumb_func` flag by the linker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to tell the assembler to use the unified syntax and explicitly declare your function to be a thumb function. The GNU assembler has directives for that:

```
  .syntax unified
  .section .text
  .thumb_func
  .global asmJump
asmJump:
```

The `.syntax unified` directive tells the assembler that you are using the modern syntax for assembly code. I think this is an unfortunate relic of some legacy syntax.

The `.thumb_func` directive tells the assembler that this function will be executed in thumb mode, so the value that is used for the symbol `asmJump` has its LSB set to one. When a Cortex-M executes a branch it checks the LSB of the target address to see if it is a one. If it is, then the target code is executed in thumb mode. Since that is the only mode supported by the Cortex-M, it will fault if the LSB of the target address is a zero.

Comment: That worked! I'm going to search for why that worked, but if you're feeling generous and expand your answer it would be help me a lot. Regardless, you solved my problem, thanx!

Comment: Thanks again. I have found an explanation for this in another SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368360/arm-thumb-using-bx-in-thumb-code-to-call-a-thumb-function-or-to-jump-to-a-thu

Comment: I have tried running the code without the `.syntax unified` but it seems to fail. I'm not sure why this would be the case. Could you please include an explanation in your answer if you have one?

Comment: For those coming from x86: ARM switches Thumb instruction encoding on / off at the same time that it runs a `blx` (`call`) instruction. That is why `.thumb_funct` is a per-function thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention you have the debugger working, use it!

Look at the fault status registers to [determine the fault source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764119/arm-cortex-m3-how-do-i-determine-the-program-counter-value-before-a-hard-fault). Maybe it's not `asmJump` crashing but the code you're invoking.

Comment: thanks, and I will. I was in the process of setting up my error handlers so that I can pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your all your code.. I suppose your change of SP called the segment error or something like that.
You should save your SP before changing it and restore it after the use of it.

```
ldr r6, =registerbackup
str sp, [r6]
#your code
...
ldr r6, =registerbackup
ldr sp, [r6]
```

Comment: You would normally be right. But since this is a bootloader I'm intentionally setting the stack pointer without a backup option. The new stack pointer address is what I have read from the Vector Table of the code which I am trying to load. Sorry if I hadn't made that clearer.

Comment: So the problem was an arm calling a thumb function. There you go. Great u found the root cause.